# Why `dpkg -S /var/lib/dpkg` shows "base-files, dpkg"?

Tags: package-management

I'm curious to know which package provides the `/var/lib/dpkg` directory, so i run this command

```
$ dpkg -S /var/lib/dpkg
base-files, dpkg: /var/lib/dpkg
```

The resulted output displays the package  which provides `/var/lib/dpkg` along with `base-files` string like the above.

```
$ dpkg -S /var/lib/aptitude
aptitude: /var/lib/aptitude
$ dpkg -S /var/lib/apt
apt: /var/lib/apt
```

But i didn't see any `base-files` string on the above output. Ofcourse files inside `/var/lib/apt` directory is also essential for an Ubuntu system to run.

So Why `dpkg -S /var/lib/dpkg` command shows "base-files,"  string ? Why it isn't displayed on the others?

Answer (score 2):

You are searching for a directory, not a specific file/binary, so any package can install files inside a directory:

```
➜  ~  dpkg -L dpkg | grep '/var/lib/dpkg'
/var/lib/dpkg
/var/lib/dpkg/info
/var/lib/dpkg/updates
/var/lib/dpkg/parts
/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives
➜  ~  dpkg -L base-files | grep '/var/lib/dpkg'
/var/lib/dpkg
➜  ~
```

As you can see, `base-files` also creates the `/var/lib/dpkg` directory (exact reason why, I ignore it, maybe there were some files now deleted, but the changelog doesn't give any obvious hint) and the dpkg package which apart of being owner of the `/var/lib/dpkg` directory, installed files inside it.